# In Laravel, instead of the error template, SW.js is practiced

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I used to create errors templates

```
php artisan vendor: public --tag = Laravel-Terorors
```

But instead of calling the page 404, for some reason, SW.js with a disorder "Page Not Found!"
Teams

```
php artisan Cache: Clear
php artisan Config: Clear
php artisan Optimize: Clear
php artisan Route: Cache
```

did not work
How to fix the conclusion of error pages?